# How to make a keymap for a series of action atomic (which can be undo by just press one time 'u')?

Tags: key-bindings, undo-redo

Here is my keymap:

```
nmap <A-y> viW<Plug>VSurround]%a()<ESC>h"+pF(<CR>l
vmap <A-y> <Plug>VSurround]%a()<ESC>h"+pF(<CR>l
```

Which is a markdown link paste helper. It will make the word "Apple" to "[Apple](url in your clipboard)".

It works fine.

But when I want to undo it (change the text back to "Apple") I need press 3 times `u` which is unconvenient for me.

How to make it atomic (just press one time `u`)?

I do some search work but cant get related topic.

Answer (score 1):

To have an atomique operation I would avoid 'Surround' and do:

```
vnoremap <A-y> "ac[<C-r>a](<C-r>+)<Esc>
nmap <A-y> viW<A-y>
```

It is simple but override the `a` buffer.

Another solution that doesn't override the `a` buffer is:

```
vnoremap <A-y> <Esc>a](<C-r>+)<Esc>gvo<Esc>i[<Esc>
nmap <A-y> viW<A-y>
```

It uses the visual selection `v`, the visual reselection `gv` and the cursor movement around the selection `o`.

Comment: Since you have a visual mode mapping, why not use it in the normal mode mapping as in `nmap viW<A-y>`?

Comment: @romainl Thanks for the hint I have updated the solution :-)

Comment: I am pretty sure that wrapping the RHS in a function (using `normal`, probably) and calling it from the mapping makes `u` work as expected.